# How to understand unicode and utf-8

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8

I have read unicode how-to from python docs and unicode tutorial from w3schools but I am still unclear about converting strings to unicode and encodings like utf-8.

I understand that in ascii and latin-1 charsets and encodings, the characters get converted to their binary representation when stored in file.

Am I correct in believing that unicode characters which require more that one byte to represent are converted into their binary representation using encoding such as utf-8 and stored in file and while reading them back I must use utf-8 encoding to decode them.

Now I copied some unicode from a webpage తెలుగులిపి and stored it in a file using normal open("new.txt", "w") function and it worked. This 5 Telugu charactes are occupying 30 bytes in that file. I am able to read these back. How is this conversion happend correctly even when I am not specifying utf-8 encoding?

```
with open("new.txt") as file_2_read:
text = file_2_read.read()
print text, len(text), type(text)
utext = text.decode('utf-8')
with open("new1.txt", "w") as file_2_write:
    file_2_write.write(text)

$ python u1.py 
తెలుగులిపి 30 <type 'str'>
తెలుగులిపి 10 <type 'unicode>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
with open("new.txt") as file_2_read:
    text = file_2_read.read()

print text, len(text), type(text)    # తెలుగులిపి 30 <type 'str'>

utext = text.decode('utf-8')
print utext, len(utext), type(utext) # తెలుగులిపి 10 <type 'unicode>
```

This is what happens here:

```
with open("new.txt") as file_2_read:
    text = file_2_read.read()
```

Python reads some sequence of bytes from a file, it's like `\xe0\xb0\xa4\xe0\xb1\x86...`. This sequence corresponds to the utf8 encoding of your original string -- but Python has no idea about that. It's just a chunk of bytes.

```
print text, len(text)
```

Python sends these bytes directly to the console. Your console encoding happens to be utf8 as well, so you see the right characters. There are 30 bytes in 'text', so there's "30".

```
utext = text.decode('utf-8')
```

We convert bytes into unicode and get a string with 10 unicode characters. This is basically an array of "codepoints" (=numbers).

```
print utext, len(utext)
```

Now, to print a unicode string, Python needs to convert it back to bytes. It uses `sys.stdout.encoding`, which happens to be utf8 too, generates some sequence of bytes (`\xe0\xb0\xa4\xe0\xb1\x86...` yet again) and sends that to the console. There are 10 codepoints in `utext`, so there's "10".

NB: the above applies only to python2, not to py3.

Comment: Thanks a lot georg! One more thing; when I use decode() on <str> it converts it to unicode then are those 10 characters unicode codepoints and not utf-8 codepoints? I am unable to get my head around what encode() and decode() does on <str> and what encode() does on <unicode>. Could you please provide some text/book which would clear this for me. Thanks again!

Comment: @anukalp: yes, a "codepoint" can only be "unicode", there are no "utf-8" (or any other encoding) codepoints.

Comment: @anukalp: yes, confusing stuff. Be sure to read http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html and http://kunststube.net/encoding/